# UITapGestureRecognizer every value the same

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm a newbie to this and remaking an app. I am trying to use UITapGestureRecognizer. It works in the initial project file but not the new one. The only difference is that the old one uses a navigational controller but mine doesn't.

In the new one the self distance:location to:centre is stuck at 640 no matter where you press on the screen.

Can anyone help? I have no idea why it isn't working.

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];
    CGPoint centre   = CGPointMake(512,768 / 2);

    NSInteger msg = [self distance:location to:centre];
    NSLog(@"location to centre: %d", msg);

    if ([self distance:location to:centre] < 330)
```

Comment: `[recognizer.view superview]` looks suspicious to me. What view is this? Try to replace it with `recognizer.view`

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much! Would the superview have been something to do with the navigation controller the other version had?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part that looks suspicious to me is `[recognizer.view superview]`.

When the gesture recognizer was added to `self.view` in a UIViewController that is not inside a container controller (e.g. a Navigation Controller) that view does not have a superview. If you send the superview message to self.view without a container view controller it will return nil.

So your message looked basically like this

```
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:nil];
```

This will return the location in the window, which is also a valid CGPoint that tells you were you tapped the screen.
Since this didn't work I guess in `[self distance:location to:centre]` you do something that does only work with coordinates relative to the view. Maybe it's related to rotation, because the coordinates of the window don't rotate when you rotate the device. 
Without knowing your code I'm not sure what the problem is, but it probably doesn't matter.

Just replace `[recognizer.view superview]` with `recognizer.view`.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below Link, You may get your answer. It's an example if Gesture Recognition.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_iOS_6_Gesture_Recognition_Tutorial